# I want to create a simple APK that only copies its contents to SD card

Tags: android, zip, apk, sd-card

I'd like to take a few zip files - file1.zip file2.zip file3.zip etc. and create an APK file which contains them and when installed simply copies them to a specified directory on the sd card of the phone.

Can this be done in just a few lines of code? I really appreciate any input. Thank you.

Comment: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4447477/android-how-to-copy-files-in-assets-to-sdcard

Answer (score 0):

Anything you put in res/raw is available as a resource you can work with once your app is installed. I'm curious why you want to move zip files to the device without having a "real" app to go with them.

Comment: Hey Joe, I simply want to add the necessary files so that I can install themes to an existing application (which isn't mine but has user made themes). So all I really need is for the APK to write its contents onto SD in the directory where the other app looks for them.

edit: Just to make myself clear, I'm not making an 'entire' app... I'm just looking for the APK to copy files to sd.